# Using Konjunktiv I to quote before mentioning name

Tags: subjunctive

From Der Spiegel:

> Der Westen wird sich den Osten einverleiben und die Früchte der Revolution in Gewinne seiner Unternehmen umwandeln. Von der DDR wird nichts bleiben, ihre Bürger müssen sich fremden Verhältnissen unterwerfen. Es kommt zu einer Übernahme, zu der die Revolutionäre freundlich eingeladen haben, die aber feindlich ausgeführt wird, als Vertilgung, Ausmerzung dessen, was der deutsche Osten einmal war.
>
> Das waren Erwartungen, nachdem die Euphorie der Revolution verflogen war. Noch schlimmer: Die aufgepumpte Bundesrepublik **könne** sich rückwärts entwickeln, zu einem neualten Reich des Büsen. Der Schriftsteller Günter Grass sagte im Februar 1990: "Die grauenhafte Erfahrung Auschwitz schließt einen deutschen Einheitsstaat aus."

The Konjunktiv I "könne" is used in the sentence **before** the sentence where the name of the person, Günter Grass, is mentioned. In cases like this, can we nevertheless always infer that this person is the one who expressed that sentence? Also, is this kind of usage recommended?

Comment: Was kommt denn vor dem zitierten Stück? Ich nehme an, dass eher das den Konjunktiv begründet.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Kein anderer Name kommt davor. Ich habe das Stück erweitert. Was denkst du jetzt?

Comment: @boaten Die Eröffnung oder Einleitung dieses Textstücks fehlt noch immer. Nichtsdestotrotz ist klar, dass alle Sätze bis auf den letzten die Befürchtungen einer Bevölkerungsgruppe beschreiben. Wahrscheinlich wird weiter vorher klar gemacht, wer so fühlt und denkt. Warum gibtst du nicht die genaue Quelle an, dann können wir mal selbst nachlesen?

Comment: @what Das ist eigentlich schon der Anfang des Artikels, den ich hier zitiert habe. Es gibt nichts weiter vorher. Du kannst gerne hier nachlesen: https://magazin.spiegel.de/digital/index_SP.html#SP/2014/38/129211305

Comment: @boaten Danke, aha. Der Autor des Artikels beschreibt also, wie er die Stimmung in Deutschland damals wahrgenommen hat: "man" (wer immer das ist) erwartete das Beschriebene. **Beispielhaft für diese allgemeine Stimmungslage** sagte Grass, was er sagte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything special in this sentence. "könne" relates to "Das waren Erwartungen, nachdem die Euphorie der Revolution verflogen war.", basically the same as in:

> Er erwartet, dass es noch schlimmer kommt: die aufgepumpte Bundesrepublik **könne** sich rückwärts entwickeln, zu einem neualten Reich des Bösen.

"könne" is indirect speech triggered by "erwarten".

I would not infer that this was voiced by Günther Grass. There are general reflections about possible/feared developments of a unified Germany, and the sentence was just a common fear back then. Then, a specific quote of Günther Grass is picked out to give a specific example of one reason for such fears.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can. The Konjuntiv in the latter paragraph rather seems to be a continuation of a quotation in the former paragraph, although it is not marked as one. If no author is given, I would assume that the article's author is trying to express a general sentiment he felt at the time in the form of a fictional quote.